# Position <form:radiobuttons> vertically

Tags: html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC `<form:radiobuttons>` to display radio buttons:

```
<form:radiobuttons path="selection" items="${arraySelection}" />
```

However, it displays them horizontally. The generated HTML is as follows:

```
<span>
 <input id="selection1" type="radio" value="0"" name="selection">
 <label for"selection1">Off</label>
</span>
<span>
 <input id="selection2" type="radio" value="1"" name="selection">
 <label for"selection2">On</label>
</span>
```

How do I display them vertically?

Comment: Please do not confuse JSTL with an arbitrary 3rd party JSP taglib like the one from Spring MVC. To learn what JSTL really is, carefully read the introduction of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info I removed the irrelevant `[jstl]` tag from the question (and sanitized some poor English/terminology).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the default wrapper (which is `<span>`) to something else that you can manipulate better, like `<li>` for example.

You can use the [`element`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.radiobuttons) attribute to change the wrapper:

```
<ul>
  <form:radiobuttons path="selection" items="${arraySelection}" element="li" />
</ul>
```

It's then just a matter of styling it how you want:

```
ul.verticalRadios {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* or whatever */
}

...

<ul class="verticalRadios">
  <form:radiobuttons path="selection" items="${arraySelection}" element="li" />
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form:radiobuttons path="selection" items="${arraySelection}" element="br" />
```

Just some suggestion, it depend situation, sometime can be done only with element "br", without need of extra css.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without an extra css file

```
<ul style="list-style: none">
    <form:radiobuttons path="selection" items="${arraySelection}" element="li" />
</ul>
```